# Sharepoint List in a DATATABLE (DATAREADER / DATASET)

Tags: list

How I can (if I can) read a sharepoint LIST in a DATATABLE way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i understand your query, you can use following code:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://yourserver/"))
{
   using(var web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
      var list = web.GetList("YourListUrl");
      var dataTable = list.Items.GetDataTable();
      // your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to a coded solution, you can always go to the LIST-tab and hit the Quick Edit Button and you have your datatable rigt out of the box.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Benny but I nne it programatically ;)